# Why is my AJAX request in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use an external AJAX page to do something with PHP that inserts into my SQL database. I have tried to import a Wordpress class which is not working.

```
function accept_request(friend_id, user_id, status){
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: myAjax.theme_dir +'callbacks/friend_action.php',
            data:{'friend_id':friend_id, 'user_id':user_id, 'status':status},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                //location.reload();
             }
            });
          }
```

and the php code is

```
//require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/choice/wp-load.php");
require_once("C:/xampp/htdocs/choice/wp-load.php");
global $wpdb; 
$friend_id=$_POST['friend_id'];
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$status=$_POST['status'];


if($status=="D"){
    $wpdb->query("delete from Friends_list where user_id='".$user_id."' and Friend_id='".$friend_id."'");
}
else{
    echo $friend_id.$user_id.$status;
    $wpdb->query("Update Friends_list set status='".$status."' where user_id='".$user_id."' and Friend_id='".$friend_id."'");
}
```

Comment: What is 'not working' ? Which error code do you receive ?

Comment: require_once("C:/xampp/htdocs/choice/wp-load.php"); this is wat the error i guess

Comment: you are vulnerable from SQL injection.

Comment: yep i am aware of that

Comment: Undefined variable issues I guess?

Comment: i can able to print all those variables

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [standard guide to implement ajax](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) in wordpress.
You need to do following

1. Make proper ajax call
2. Create function to handle the request
3. Add function to hook
4. Create success/error or other handlers as needed